# Can I debug a compiled assembly?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I am looking for a way to debug compiled assemblies from Visual Studio.

Is it possible? Maybe using some kind of reflector add-in?

I am *not* looking for a way to decompile/recompile and then debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the PDB files for the assembly, try using [.Net Reflector Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), which was released a few days ago. It can decompile the code on-the-fly in Visual Studio and then step through it as if you were debugging your own source code (**it does not require you to decompile and then recompile again**). It is a paid for Visual Studio addin, but comes with a 14 day trial, after which it reverts back to the free version of Reflector.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can accomplish this is to disable the "Just My code" feature (Tools -> Options -> Debugging) and then load the PDB for the DLL.  After that you will be able to step into the DLL without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, no problem.  As long as you got the .pdb file.  The debugging experience isn't as rich, you'll frequently be unable to inspect local variables and single-stepping behaves odd at times.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to a running process using Debug -> Attach to Process.  As long as you have a copy of the running source code with the .pdb in Visual Studio, you can debug normally.