# debug doesn't enter inside AddCors method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In startup.cs I have AddCors to services, I want to debug code from inside of AddCors, but Breackpoint doesn't fire inside

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                //debug didn't fire here
                var corsOrigins = configuration["cors-origins"].Split(",");
                if ((corsOrigins.Length == 1)
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                        builder => builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials());
                }
                else
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                        builder => builder.WithOrigins(corsOrigins)
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials());
                }
            });
```

any ideas how can I stop code execution inside AddCors method?

Comment: I would expect it ought to be evaluated when you make a request with CORS headers.

Comment: I want to test from unit test debugger, looks like is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options builder inside will be evaluated when a request comes into the API. This is essentially because the middleware receives an `IOptions<CorsOptions>` from the container and evaluates its `.Value` property.

We can simulate this. Imagine you're building the container:

```cs
ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        var corsOrigins = configuration["cors-origins"].Split(",");
        if ((corsOrigins.Length == 1)
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        }
        else
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins(corsOrigins)
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        }
    });

IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
CorsOptions options = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<CorsOptions>>().Value;
```

Obviously you can allow ASP.NET Core to build the services, etc. you just need access to the `IServiceProvider` somewhere to retrieve the options from the container. This should hit your breakpoint inside the lambda function, or let you directly check the resulting `CorsOptions` object.

Answer (score -1):

Because AddCors is a method from a compiled assembly without a debug info and you can't debug inside of such assemblies without [special tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284748/can-i-debug-a-compiled-assembly). Without the tools the easiest way would be to get a [source code for asp.net core](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore) and add it to your solution.